# Find area inside closed object in ios

Tags: ios, geometry, area

I want to calculate the `area` inside an object which is any closed object like `rectangle` ,`square` ,`polygon` etc.

[image]

I can not get exact solution to do this.Please help to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220719/ios-how-to-calculate-number-of-pixels-area-enclosed-by-a-curve

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary polygons with known vertice coordinates you can use [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

```
A = 1/2 * Abs(Sum{i=0..n-1} (X[i] * Y[i+1] - X[i+1] * Y[i]) )
```

where for `i=n-1` take `i+1=0`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method which will give me closed object's area.It may be helpful for you.

```
-(double)areaWithXpts :(NSArray *)xpts withYpts :(NSArray *)ypts totalPoints :(int)numPoints
{
  double area=0;
  int j=numPoints-1;
   for(int i=0 ; i < numPoints;i++)
   {
       area=area+([[xpts objectAtIndex:j] floatValue]+[[xpts objectAtIndex:i] floatValue])*([[ypts objectAtIndex:j] floatValue]-[[ypts objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]);
       j=i;
   }
  double areaVal=area/2;
  NSLog(@"Area is :%f",areaVal);

  return areaVal;
}
```

Usage :

Array of X points

```
NSArray *xArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"10", @"10",  @"29",nil];
```

Array of Y points

```
NSArray *yArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"26", @"26", @"4",nil];
```

Total points = Array count.

**Note**: x array and y array both have same count.

```
double objectArea = [self areaWithXpts:xArray withYpts:yArray totalPoints:4];
```

Or you can check this answer also - [Area calculation in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649172/wrong-area-calculation-objective-c?rq=1)

And about area with curve shape object : you can find reference from this link - [Curve shape object area reference](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/4514516)